# Misaligned divs

Tags: html, css, firefox

The below list of divs do not get horizontally aligned when the browser window is enlarged to fit at list 2 divs horinzontally. I can't figure out why. If I use the same text in all the div's paragraphs then it aligns. I'm using Firefox 32.0 in Fedora 20.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    .item_div {display: inline-block; border: 1px solid grey; width: 450px; height: 230px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;}
    .item_div img {float:left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; width: 220; height: 220; border: 1px solid grey;}
    .item_div p {margin: 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>irure ullamco in adipisicing in laborum enim exercitation voluptate quis ex sint id ut tempor amet, reprehenderit commodo qui aute</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>quis occaecat commodo reprehenderit in do non sed dolor aliqua. deserunt amet, sunt eiusmod officia cupidatat ipsum veniam, Excepteur dolore</p>
    </div>
        <div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>Lorem ea aute minim in velit adipisicing aliquip enim eiusmod pariatur. in nostrud qui voluptate tempor ullamco non in dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>dolore ut aliquip consequat. cupidatat cillum dolor quis proident, amet, dolore nulla minim culpa ad incididunt nisi aliqua. eiusmod officia</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: misaligned divs]

Comment: try to put float:left; on .item_div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>irure ullamco in adipisicing in laborum enim exercitation voluptate quis ex sint id ut tempor amet, reprehenderit commodo qui aute</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>quis occaecat commodo reprehenderit in do non sed dolor aliqua. deserunt amet, sunt eiusmod officia cupidatat ipsum veniam, Excepteur dolore</p>
    </div><!--
        --><div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>Lorem ea aute minim in velit adipisicing aliquip enim eiusmod pariatur. in nostrud qui voluptate tempor ullamco non in dolor</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="item_div">
        <a>
        <img width="220" height="220">
        </a>
        <p>dolore ut aliquip consequat. cupidatat cillum dolor quis proident, amet, dolore nulla minim culpa ad incididunt nisi aliqua. eiusmod officia</p>
    </div>
        </div>
```

And this CSS:

```
  .item_div {display: block; float:left; border: 1px solid grey; width: 450px; height: 230px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;}
    .item_div img {float:left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; width: 220; height: 220; border: 1px solid grey;}
    .item_div p {margin: 0;}

#main:after { clear:both; content: ""; display:block; }
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mceohpkn/